# Formula not returning the desired value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to compute tax for the specified cells

[image]

This is the formula i am using:

```
=IF(C3<=180000;0*C3;IF(C3>180000&C3<=500000;0.1*C3;IF(C3>500000&C3<=800000;0.2*C3;0.3*C3)))
```

The problem is that only 1st two conditions are working and the rest are not.

Comment: Have you tried using the evaluate formula button? It shows, step by step, how the formula has been evaluated for a certain cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `&` in your formula, aggregate the two conditions with `AND` like so:

```
=IF(C3<=180000;0*C3;IF(AND(C3>180000;C3<=500000);0.1*C3;IF(AND(C3>500000;C3<=800000);0.2*C3;0.3*C3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many things here:

1. The '&' is concatenate operator and will not work as logical 'AND'. so the condition will never evaluate to TRUE as expected.
2. Cell 'C3' is not identified in your example and left open for assumption.
3. I understand what you are trying to calculate. You will not get expected correct result even if that formula is corrected for syntax because it doesn't follow the logic.

Try this formula in Tax payable

```
=IF(C3<=180000,C3*0,IF(C3<=500000,(C3-180000)*0.1+0,IF(C3<=800000,(C3-500000)*0.2+(500000-180000)*0.1+0,(C3-800000)*0.3+(800000-500000)*0.2+(500000-180000)*0.1+0)))
```

Edit: replace ',' with ';' as per locale

Explanation:

This is slab based taxation and the total income is subjected to slabs for computation of tax. For example if income is 600000

the first 180000 is taxed at 0%  = 0

the next 320000 earned is taxed at 10% = 32000

the next 100000 is taxed at 20% = 20000

Total tax = 52000